# Vibration (shaking) elements in Box2D after using the Apply Force

Tags: javascript, box2d, game-physics

Sorry for my bad English.

I do a little game in *JavaScript* using Box2D (although I think the language is not important, because the engine is the same, as is well known, and has been exported to JavaScript).

Connecting several bodies via Distance Joint. When creating a joint pointing `frequencyHz = 11` and `dampingRatio = 0` (as I understand it, the less `dampingRatio`, the faster the item returns to its original position, that is, the spring will be tougher that I need). For each body to use force:

```
body.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(0, 5800), body.GetWorldCenter())
```

That I needed to have these bodies was greater gravity than others.

After creating several elements, they begin to twitch, to vibrate as if they were something haunted, stop and engage in a certain position.

I tried to "play" with parameters `frequencyHz` and `dampingRatio` have *joint*, and sought to design not twitch, but then the construction seems less harsh and smoother.

There is some sort of solution?

Thanks.

I think that the structure is vibrating due to the fact that the weight of several elements, and the power applicable to them, the object is pulled down by increasing the length of the joint, the joint is aimed szhimatsya back to its original position, due to this vibration is obtained, because the element moves quickly in different directions

Comment: Have you tried to remove the gravity? I.E. set the gravity value to 0

Comment: Yes, i tried to remove the gravity, but no changes

Comment: have you tried to force the velocity of the blocks to 0? So the X and Y velocity are reset? Just to let you know I have never used box2d

Comment: I try, but i cant set linear velocity of body to zero, because applied force is set velocity to non-zero

Comment: I understand that the Distance Joint as a spring pulls the body back, but considering that the force applied to the body more, it should not be pulled back. Another great strength, I can not give, as in this case, the body will just fall like a stone.

Comment: So there are parts connected to the body, but the body shouldn't move? But the body does move when force is added to the parts that are connected to it yea?

Comment: No, the body needs to move. When the body is put, it connects the two joints with other Closest bodies. Because of the severity of Sealy, the body must fall down, but keeps his joints. In order to be joint spring, I added him frequencyHz. Now the body springs and stops. But when a lot of bodies in the chain, the whole structure begins to vibrate. I assume from the fact that the joint is stretched, trying to return to its original position.